# IE 11 box-sizing issue (not working when adding border or padding)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-lists

I have an `<ul>` where each `<li>` should **split the available width** in five:

```
<ul class="other-languages-products-list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

The following CSS works fine in Chrome and Firefox (latest) but fails in Internet Explorer 11, where last `<li>` goes on a new line and only four are displayed in a row:

```
.other-languages-products-list {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.other-languages-products-list li {
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.other-languages-products-list:before,
.other-languages-products-list:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}

.other-languages-products-list:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Is this a know bug or I'm missing something?

Comment: Looks the same in [Chrome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vooU4.png) and [IE](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5YraH.png) for me. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbfs0k1L/)

Comment: @quantumwannabe what doctype Fiddle is using? Is this importat for box-sizing to work? Because I'm on old XHTML 1.0 Transitional...

Comment: It's on HTML5. This fiddle is on XHTML 1.0 Transisitional: http://jsfiddle.net/cbfs0k1L/1/. I still don't see the error in IE11 or Chrome.

Comment: @quantumwannabe I've found the problem (it was a meta). Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem! I don't know why who coded the page used:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Forcing `Edge` (latest) version of the rendering engine (of course) solves the problem. IE7 doesn't support `box-sizing` and a lot of other stuff.